# Convert decimal fraction to binary number

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, keil

I have this code that works for me to convert a double into a binary representation, I want to know how to convert the Fractional Part if it were separately.

Example Function Prototype would be:

```
    int decimalToBinary (int Integral, int Fractional, int k_prec);
```

```
// Function to convert decimal to binary upto 
// k-precision after decimal point 
int decimalToBinary(double num, int k_prec) 
{ 
    //int binary = 0; 
    int NumF=0;
    // Fetch the integral part of decimal number 
    int Integral = num; 
    int count=0;
    // Fetch the fractional part decimal number 
    double Fractional = num - Integral; 
  
    // Conversion of integral part to 
    // binary equivalent 
    while (Integral) 
    { 
        int rem = Integral % 2; 
        
        rem=rem&0x01;
        
        NumF=NumF|(rem<<count);
  
        Integral /= 2; 
        
        count=count+1;
    } 
  
    NumF<<=k_prec;
    
    // Conversion of fractional part to 
    // binary equivalent 
    while (k_prec--) 
    { 
        // Find next bit in fraction 
        Fractional *= 2; 
        int fract_bit = Fractional; 
  
        if (fract_bit == 1) 
        { 
            Fractional -= fract_bit; 
            NumF=NumF|(0x01<<k_prec); 
        } 
        else
            NumF=NumF|(0x00<<k_prec);
    } 
  
    return NumF; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you will get a better answer on SO, because this is a pure software question.

Comment: This would not really fit on SO either, because stack exchange sites are not a code writing service (rules are that such generally misfit questions are to be closed at the source site, not migrated)   Think about how you would perform this operation manually - eg, subtract the integer part, and then perhaps multiply the decimal part by whatever precision you want and then convert that to an integer by truncation or rounding...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about EE, and it isn't suitable for migration, either.

Comment: @DaveTweed agree about the closure, but your successive multiplication by 10 would lead to a BCD output, not a binary output.  Granted, that might be lack of clarity on the asker's part...